# How to store data in JSONField

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have a django model named Fixture

```
class Fixture(models.Model):                                   
   fixture = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)            
   league_id = models.ForeignKey('League',null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, to_field="league")
   teams_h2h = JSONField(null=True)
   home_team_id = models.IntegerField(null=True)              
   away_team_id = models.IntegerField(null=True)
   half_time_score = models.CharField(max_length=30,null=True)
   full_time_score = models.CharField(max_length=30,null=True))
```

The Fixture object in my app store the data of soccer match between to teams. Fixture model have **teams_h2h** field which is JSONField and i put there the data of previous soccer matchs between both commands. Here is my question. I have a list of fixture ids which i want to store inside  **teams_h2h** field. In which data format i should put data into it?? List or dictionary??

Comment: You can store data in form of dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

You may use dictionary data type.

But should must consider using another option like ArrayField, because JSONField is specific for PostgreSQL.

[In Documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/contrib/postgres/fields/#django.contrib.postgres.fields.JSONField) about data types:

> A field for storing JSON encoded data. In Python the data is represented in its Python native format: **dictionaries, lists, strings, numbers, booleans** and **None**.

and about SQL support:

> **PostgreSQL has two native JSON based data types: json and jsonb**. The main difference between them is how they are stored and how they can be queried. PostgreSQL’s **json field** is **stored** as the original **string** representation of the **JSON** and **must be decoded** on the fly when queried based on keys. The jsonb field is stored based on the actual structure of the JSON which allows indexing. The trade-off is a small additional cost on writing to the jsonb field. **JSONField uses jsonb**.